# Pass PHP array into Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

Referring to the title. I have an array which I coded like this:-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM server";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$dServer = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dServer[] = $row['model'];
}
```

Now, how do I pass the **$dServer** array into a Javascript array?

For example, this array:

```
var a = new Array();
```

Comment: pass all the array from $dServer into a.

Comment: Please use the search function. About 1/4 of the questions in the "Related" sidebar answer your question.

Comment: @zerkms If they used quotes it would make `a` a string rather than a variable defined by JSON.

Comment: @jprofitt: oops, missed that it is not an ajax response, but inline JS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM server";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$dServer = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $dServer[] = $row['model'];
}    

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = <?php echo json_encode($dServer); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Encode it as a json object.

```
<?
    $arr = array('entry' => 'content');
?>

<script>
var data = <?=json_encode($arr);?>;
alert(data['entry']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get use of ajax request and [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php).

Second variant

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM server";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$dServer = array();

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
              $dServer[] = $row['model'];
      }    
?>
var a = <?php echo json_encode($dServer);?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ajax / json methods mentioned, you can directly print out the values:

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM server";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = new Array();

<?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "a['model'] = " . $row['model'] . ";"; 
    echo "a['nextField'] = " . $row['nextField'] . ";"; 
  }
?>
</script>
```