# how can I pass php array to Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass php array to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-php-array-to-javascript-function)
>   [Pass PHP array into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220642/pass-php-array-into-javascript-array)

I got problem pass the PHP data to Javascript. I need to transfer the addr column to array then pass array to Javascript , how can i fetch it out of PHP then use array in Javascript? thank you

```
<?php
  require_once 'Common/system_start.php';
  $sql="select addr from tab_mem order by sn desc ";
  $result=  mysql_query($sql);
  $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $row=mysql_num_rows($result);
  $n = array(); 
  for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++) 
  { 
   $data=mysql_fetch_row($result); 
   $n[i] = $data[i]; 
  } 

  ?>
```

Comment: Is this an API to which the js connects to, to get data, or does this php script output a page with javascript?

Comment: no, this my PHP code, I wish people can help me out to get the var from it. :-)

Comment: Question was closed. I didn't ask if it's your code, I just wanted to know which way you want the data. AJAX call to php script or does the php script output the complete html code including javascript.

Comment: Probably you will need an ajax call to get the array from php

Comment: I am so sorry I was misunderstanding. I need to fetch the Address data from database then pass it to my Geocoder for google map. I don't know which way is the best way to do it. thanks for your asking.

Comment: how can I use the Ajax to call the array, I did try for few days, but I cannot do anything!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
var jsArray = ["<?php echo join("\", \"", $n); ?>"];
alert(jsArray);
</script>
```